# Is it normal when installing DE's, the boot up screen changes?

Tags: xubuntu

(DE's = Desktop Environments.)

I was looking for a lightweight DE,when i started thinking about Xubuntu.

I installed it,and i had to reboot my Asus Eee laptop because of updates.

When it booted up,there was a Xubuntu bootup screen.

Is that normal?

Comment: yes, I believe it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you installed the `xubuntu-desktop`, then it replaces the boot splash, but you can change the boot splash if you want to.